# How to protect the slots of the root function (besides the written slots of ours) when defining a new function in R?

Tags: r, function, slot

I have written a function that depends on unitrootTest of fUnitroots:

I want to add and use new slots besides the one that come from unitrootTest:

```
library(fUnitRoots)
adfcs1 <- function(t, max = floor(12*(length(t)/100)^(1/4)), type = c("c")) {
x <- ts(t)
x1d <- diff(x, differences=1)
x1l <- lag(x, -1)

x_names <- c("x1d", "x1l", sapply(1:max, function(i) paste("x1d", i, "l", sep="")))
for (i in as.integer(1:max)) { assign(x_names[i+2], lag(x1d, -i)) }
DLDlag <- do.call(ts.intersect, sapply(x_names, as.symbol))
DLDlag.df <- data.frame(DLDlag, obspts = c(time(DLDlag)))
DifferenceLags <- as.vector(names(DLDlag.df), mode="any")[3: (length(DLDlag.df)-1)]

lmresults <- array(list())
SBCvalues <- array(list())
AICvalues <- array(list())

for (i in as.integer(0:max)) {  

if (type==c("nc")) {    
if (i == 0) { lmresults[[max+1]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~x1l")),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[max+1]] <- BIC(lmresults[[max+1]])
AICvalues[[max+1]] <- AIC(lmresults[[max+1]]) }
if (i > 0) { lmresults[[i]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ x1l+", paste(DifferenceLags[1:i], collapse="+"))),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[i]] <- BIC(lmresults[[i]])
AICvalues[[i]] <- AIC(lmresults[[i]]) }
}

if (type==c("c")) {     
if (i == 0) { lmresults[[max+1]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~1+x1l")),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[max+1]] <- BIC(lmresults[[max+1]])
AICvalues[[max+1]] <- AIC(lmresults[[max+1]]) }
if (i > 0) { lmresults[[i]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ 1+x1l+", paste(DifferenceLags[1:i], collapse="+"))),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[i]] <- BIC(lmresults[[i]])
AICvalues[[i]] <- AIC(lmresults[[i]]) }
}

if (type==c("ct")) {    
if (i == 0) { lmresults[[max+1]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ 1+x1l+seq_along(x1d)",collapse="")),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[max+1]] <- BIC(lmresults[[max+1]])
AICvalues[[max+1]] <- AIC(lmresults[[max+1]]) }
if (i > 0) { lmresults[[i]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ 1+x1l+seq_along(x1d)+",paste(DifferenceLags[1:i], collapse="+"))),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[i]] <- BIC(lmresults[[i]])
AICvalues[[i]] <- AIC(lmresults[[i]]) }
}

}

list(which.min(SBCvalues), which.min(AICvalues))
as.data.frame(cbind(SBCvalues, AICvalues)) 
typespecified <- type
if (which.min(SBCvalues)==max+1) {
scs <- (max+2)-(0+1)
adfcs1 <- unitrootTest(x[scs:length(x)], lags = 0, type = typespecified)  
} else {
scs <- (max+2)-(which.min(SBCvalues)+1)
adfcs1 <- unitrootTest(x[scs:length(x)], lags =which.min(SBCvalues), type = typespecified)
 }
adfcs1 
}
```

When I added @test slot, even though I did not define it in adfcs1, it automatically retrieve the detailed "Coefficients" results from unitrootTest (as I wanted):

```
> adfcs1(f1f.zs,max=1,type="c")@test
$data.name
[1] "x[scs:length(x)]"

$regression
Call:
lm(formula = y.diff ~ y.lag.1 + 1)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.49700 -0.12039  0.06813  0.26813  0.77105 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.05766    0.04631  -1.245    0.216    
y.lag.1     -0.47631    0.08387  -5.679 1.36e-07 ***
.....
$statistic
       DF 
-5.679303 

$p.value
           t            n 
4.216696e-06 3.641807e-01 

$parameter
Lag Order 
        0
```

When I want to use my defined slots (optmins, SBCAIC, etc.) besides the one that come from unitrootTest, it gives error this time when I add @test slot!

```
adfcs2 <- function(t, max = floor(12*(length(t)/100)^(1/4)), type = c("c")) {
x <- ts(t)
x1d <- diff(x, differences=1)
x1l <- lag(x, -1)

x_names <- c("x1d", "x1l", sapply(1:max, function(i) paste("x1d", i, "l", sep="")))
for (i in as.integer(1:max)) { assign(x_names[i+2], lag(x1d, -i)) }
DLDlag <- do.call(ts.intersect, sapply(x_names, as.symbol))
DLDlag.df <- data.frame(DLDlag, obspts = c(time(DLDlag)))
DifferenceLags <- as.vector(names(DLDlag.df), mode="any")[3: (length(DLDlag.df)-1)]

lmresults <- array(list())
SBCvalues <- array(list())
AICvalues <- array(list())

for (i in as.integer(0:max)) {  

if (type==c("nc")) {    
if (i == 0) { lmresults[[max+1]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~x1l")),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[max+1]] <- BIC(lmresults[[max+1]])
AICvalues[[max+1]] <- AIC(lmresults[[max+1]]) }
if (i > 0) { lmresults[[i]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ x1l+", paste(DifferenceLags[1:i], collapse="+"))),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[i]] <- BIC(lmresults[[i]])
AICvalues[[i]] <- AIC(lmresults[[i]]) }
}

if (type==c("c")) {     
if (i == 0) { lmresults[[max+1]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~1+x1l")),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[max+1]] <- BIC(lmresults[[max+1]])
AICvalues[[max+1]] <- AIC(lmresults[[max+1]]) }
if (i > 0) { lmresults[[i]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ 1+x1l+", paste(DifferenceLags[1:i], collapse="+"))),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[i]] <- BIC(lmresults[[i]])
AICvalues[[i]] <- AIC(lmresults[[i]]) }
}

if (type==c("ct")) {    
if (i == 0) { lmresults[[max+1]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ 1+x1l+seq_along(x1d)",collapse="")),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[max+1]] <- BIC(lmresults[[max+1]])
AICvalues[[max+1]] <- AIC(lmresults[[max+1]]) }
if (i > 0) { lmresults[[i]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ 1+x1l+seq_along(x1d)+",paste(DifferenceLags[1:i], collapse="+"))),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[i]] <- BIC(lmresults[[i]])
AICvalues[[i]] <- AIC(lmresults[[i]]) }
}

}

out <- list()

out$optmins <- list(which.min(SBCvalues), which.min(AICvalues))
out$SBCAIC <- as.data.frame(cbind(SBCvalues, AICvalues)) 
typespecified <- type
if (which.min(SBCvalues)==max+1) {
scs <- (max+2)-(0+1)
out$adfcst <- unitrootTest(x[scs:length(x)], lags = 0, type = typespecified)  
} else {
scs <- (max+2)-(which.min(SBCvalues)+1)
out$adfcst <- unitrootTest(x[scs:length(x)], lags =which.min(SBCvalues), type = typespecified)
 }
out
}

> adfcs2(t1f.zs,max=1,type="c")$optmins  # My defined slot works
[[1]]
[1] 2
[[2]]
[1] 2

> adfcs2(t1f.zs,max=1,type="c")@test 
# Whereas this time original slot that (I guess) came from unitrootTest doesn't work anymore!
Error: trying to get slot "test" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots
```

How to keep the slots that came from root function besides the ones defined in our new functions?
Am I missing something in using $ and @ properly? What is $ for? and What is @ for?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Didn't read your function carefully, but it seems that your function is returning a standard `list` object and as such doesn't have slots. If `unirootTest` returns an `S4` object with a `test` slot, you should be able to retrieve it through `adfcs2(t1f.zs,max=1,type="c")$adfcst@test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Nicola. He solved my question via his "f(...)$...@..." solution.

Solution:

```
myfunction(........)$SlotOfMyFunction@SlotOfRootFunction
```

I experienced that when our functions have their own slots, we cannot directly access the slot of root function via f(...)@SlotOfTheRootFunction.

We must exhaust one of our slots (via $) to reach the slot of the root function (via @).